# mySQL getting wrong columns that don't match up with other columns in same row

Tags: mysql

I am new to mySQL and I could use some help with the following query.

I have a table relating engine settings to an experiment number and engine rpms,
and also another table relating engine performance to experiment number and engine.

here is the query i am doing

```
SELECT performance.exp_no, performance.rpm, ignition_timing, horse_power
FROM engine_settings, performance
WHERE performance.rpm = engine_settings.rpm
ORDER BY rpm;
```

| exp_no | rpm  | ignition_timing | horse_power |

|      2 | 1000 |           24.50 |      105.23 |
|      2 | 1000 |           24.00 |      105.23 |
|      1 | 1000 |           24.50 |      100.23 |
|      1 | 1000 |           24.00 |      100.23 |
|      1 | 2000 |           25.50 |      125.03 |
|      1 | 2000 |           25.00 |      125.03 |
|      2 | 2000 |           25.50 |      129.03 |
|      2 | 2000 |           25.00 |      129.03 |
|      1 | 3000 |           26.50 |      154.65 |
|      1 | 3000 |           26.00 |      154.65 |
|      2 | 3000 |           26.50 |      159.65 |
|      2 | 3000 |           26.00 |      159.65 |
|      1 | 4000 |           27.50 |      178.23 |
|      1 | 4000 |           27.00 |      178.23 |
|      2 | 4000 |           27.50 |      184.23 |
|      2 | 4000 |           27.00 |      184.23 |
|      2 | 5000 |           28.50 |      195.36 |
|      2 | 5000 |           28.00 |      195.36 |
|      1 | 5000 |           28.50 |      189.36 |
|      1 | 5000 |           28.00 |      189.36 |

20 rows in set (0.06 sec)

Now take the first two rows for example.  Ignition_timing for experiment 2 is actually 24.00, and for experiment 1 it is 24.5.  So why do i get both values for experiment 2?

Here are the results I would like to be getting . . .

| exp_no | rpm  | ignition_timing | horse_power |
|      2 | 1000 |           24.00 |      105.23 |
|      1 | 1000 |           24.50 |      100.23 |
|      1 | 2000 |           25.50 |      125.03 |
|      2 | 2000 |           25.00 |      129.03 |
|      1 | 3000 |           26.50 |      154.65 |
|      2 | 3000 |           26.00 |      159.65 |
|      1 | 4000 |           27.50 |      178.23 |
|      2 | 4000 |           27.00 |      184.23 |
|      2 | 5000 |           28.00 |      195.36 |
|      1 | 5000 |           28.50 |      189.36 |

What is the correct query to get the above table? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow this is completely unreadable?

Comment: I have posted a answer but if you can post your table definitions I would be able to confirm that my suspicion is correct. You can execute the following and add the output to your question DESCRIBE performance  DESCRIBE engine_settings

Comment: Add a description of the two tables in question (i.e. column names)

Answer (score 0):

Just a group by/ DISCTINCT  needed

```
SELECT 
performance.exp_no, 
performance.rpm, 
ignition_timing, 
DISTINCT(horse_power)
FROM 
engine_settings 
inner join performance ON performance.rpm = engine_settings.rpm
ORDER BY rpm;
```

OR

```
  SELECT 
    performance.exp_no, 
    performance.rpm, 
    ignition_timing, 
    horse_power
    FROM 
    engine_settings 
    inner join performance ON performance.rpm = engine_settings.rpm
GROUP BY horse_power
    ORDER BY rpm;
```

Comment: I tried grouping by distinct like you said but it didn't seem to work.  I ended up changine my WHERE clause to WHERE performance.rpm = engine_settings.rpm AND performance.exp_no = engine_settings.exp_no and I got the result I wanted.

Comment: So Dan my answer is thus correct. Could you mark it as such? I suspected you where not joining on the right columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not joining on all required field. You are only joining on the rpm fields your query and it appears that the join is incomplete.

```
SELECT performance.exp_no, performance.rpm, ignition_timing, horse_power
FROM engine_settings, performance WHERE performance.rpm = engine_settings.rpm
ORDER BY rpm;
```

You should change your query to the following:

```
SELECT performance.exp_no, performance.rpm, ignition_timing, horse_power
FROM engine_settings INNER JOIN performance 
    ON engine_setting.rpm=performance.rpm 
    AND engine_Settings.exp_no = performance.exp_no
ORDER BY rpm;
```

As I dont have the table structures I might be wrong but I suspect that both rpm and exp_no is a primary key or foreign key somewhere.

Hope this helps. On a side note look at the join syntax in my example it is considered the new standard the way you are writting a join is a bit outdates but not wrong.